# Can cruise pilots/second officers go for years without doing a takeoff or landing?

Tags: pilots, cruise

I was looking at the description of this role i.e. someone who provides cruise flight relief flying. As conceivably, someone could be bonded for multiple years because of the type rating being covered by the airline, it is possible they could 'fly' for multiple years and yet never actually do a real takeoff or landing?

Comment: I believe that a pilot has to do a certain number of take-offs and landings to keep their license current.

Comment: Can you explain and link to some information about what a "cruise pilot" is? I'd never heard that term until I saw this question.

Comment: Sure. http://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/2014-11-10/easa-proposes-changes-relief-pilot-requirements

Comment: DJClayworth: I happen to know that is the answer but you deserve the credit.

Comment: This question might be better if a jurisdiction were included. In the U.S., for example, there is no such thing as a 'cruise pilot.' Relief pilots on long haul flights have the same requirements as the rest of the crew here (i.e. a minimum of one qualified Captain is _always_ on duty.) In the U.S., there is no such thing as a pilot in flight deck of an airliner at all unless they have an ATPL. Licensure requirements vary dramatically by jurisdiction, though. Additionally, the required takeoffs and landings for currency (as DJClayworth mentioned) will also likely vary by jurisdiction.

Comment: Not a definite answer, but a friend of mine flew 747's as a 2nd officer for a major airline for a number of years. He had multiple take offs and landings in a sim, but 0 actual in a front seat.

Comment: @reirab This is not strictly true. the FAA states no differences to ICAO Annex 1 - 2.1.4.1 or 2.1.4.1.1.  Therefore a US "cruise pilot" could exist. They would require the relevant class/type rating - and this class/type rating would have the limitation of the role endorsed on the rating. (see my answer for more information).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: yes

Personal Licensing regulation outlined in **Annex 1,** **2.1.4 "Circumstances in which class and type ratings are required"** states that:

> 2.1.4.1 A Contracting State having issued a pilot licence shall not permit the holder of such licence **to act either as pilot-in-command or as co-pilot** of an aeroplane, an airship, a helicopter or a powered-lift **unless** the holder has received
> authorization as follows:
>
> a) the appropriate **class rating** specified in 2.1.3.1; or
>
> b) a **type rating** when required in accordance with the provisions of 2.1.3.2.
>
> 2.1.4.1.1 When a type rating is issued limiting the privileges to act as co-
> pilot, or limiting the privileges to **act as pilot  only during
> the *cruise phase* of the flight**, **such limitation shall be endorsed on
> the rating.**
>
> *ICAO - Annex 1 - Personnnel Licensing*

Though vague about takeoff, landings, or other stages of flight, this published regulation is clear that

- Cruise pilots acting only during cruise phases of flight is allowed, providing they have the appropriate class or type rating
- The limitation of their role, such as cruise flight only,  is endorsed on the respective rating.

---

Your question didn't ask about what state/country you were asking about

- The FAA lists no differences from the above regulation in [GEN 1.7](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/part1_gen_section_1.7.html)
- Though it may differ between EASA states, it seems that EASA states also comply with the ICAO regulation in this matter. For example, see the Irish Aviation Authority (IAA) differences to Annex 1: [GEN 1.7](http://iaip.iaa.ie/iaip/Published%20Files/AIP%20Files/GEN/EI_GEN_1_7_EN.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Every airline pilot is required to maintain currency. In a 2nd officers case most of this will probably be in a full motion simulator.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. To me this does not seem to directly address the question, could you add a little more extensive reasoning?